# Unit Testing - Inner class receives null when accessing outer class fields

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, robolectric, powermockito

I'm writing unit tests for a class with an inner class. When I try to access variables belonging to the outer class from inside the inner class, they resolve to be null. However, this is only when running the unit tests.

```
class Outer {
    private final SomeClass foo;

    Outer(SomeClass foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    // + some static methods used by other tests

    class Inner {
        void doSomething() {
            assertNotNull(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter whether `Someclass` is a mock or not (could be a basic `String`), the problem still occurs.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*" })
@PrepareForTest(Outer.class)
public class OuterTest {

    Outer outer;
    SomeClass someClassMock;

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Outer.class);
        someClassMock = Mockito.mock(SomeClass.class);
        // + setup someClassMock
        outer = new Outer(someClassMock);
    }


    @Test
    public void testInner() throws Exception {
        outer.new Inner().doSomething();
    }
}
```

**EDIT** I've narrowed it down to the use of `PowerMock.mockStatic(..)`. Even though the `Inner` class is non-static, PowerMock/Mockito seem to treat it as such and handle requests to the `Outer` class as static.

Comment: Once I fix the obvious compilation issue, the test runs fine. So I think you've simplified your code to a point where it doesn't do what your actual code does. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.